# macOS androidstudio grey screen

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Hi ,
i try to uninstall and install again , i search on google if anyone had issue like this but i didnt find any result.
what can be the issue?
i also add the android studio to the Accessibility

please help.

Thank you ,

Ido

Comment: What is the Android Studio version?